# Change game mode when you click a button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two game modes in my game. And I want to know how to preload the game mode when you selected it. And load the game mode you chose when you press the play button.

My problem is when I chose a game mode it loads it immediately. I want it to wait until I press the play button.

Answer (score 0):

You can define GameModes in an `enum` then define variable to hold currently selected game mode and use that to load up the selected game mode when Play button gets pressed using a switch case.

```cs
public enum GameModes { Tag, HideAndSeek }

GameModes selectedGameMode = GameModes.Tag;
public void SelectTag(){ selectedGameMode = GameModes.Tag; }
public void SelectHideAndSeek(){ selectedGameMode = GameModes.HideAndSeek; }

public void StartGame()
{
    switch (selectedGameMode)
    {
        case GameModes.Tag:
            StartTagGame();
            break;
        case GameModes.HideAndSeek:
            StartHideAndSeekGame();
            break;
        default:
            StartTagGame();
            break;
    }
}
```